# Android: Login and Logout in all the activities

Tags: android

Am beginner to android, I have one clarification in **Login & Logout**... I will get the username and password through json....So no problem with that....

Now, there are three activities in my app.. All the activities has **"Login "** function, if i login in any of the three activities,  it should **logged in** all the activities.

And the same way , if i logout in any of the three activities,  it should **logged out** all the activities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shared preference for this. Store that boolean value isLogin true if it is login and make it false when you logout according to that display the string

Some Sample code if you do not know preference

```
public String getStringPreference(String key) {
            return settings.getString(key,  null); 
    }

    public void setStringPreference(String key, String value) {

        settings.edit().putString(key, value).commit();

    }
```

In your Activity's or Application's onCreate, call this:

```
settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Bhupendrasinh: i cant get you ..bcoz am just a beginner...Can u explain clearly ??

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged in. Save this informatio in static data member in a simple LoginState class for example :

```
public class LoginState{
     public static boolean isLogged = false;
}
```

So then when you login from any of three activities you switch its state to logged in

```
LoginState.isLogged = true;
```

Because it is a static data member all activities can access it and the value will survive orientation changes as well.

Then in each activity you can simply check if you are logged in

```
if(LoginState.isLogged){
   ...
}else{
   login()
};
```

...